# Count in Firebird 3.0 bigint vs Firebird 2.5 integer

Tags: database, delphi-7, firebird, unidac, firebird-3.0

On my system, after the migration from Firebird 2.5 to 3.0, many reports and other functions began to give problems stating that what was expected was Integer and the current one is `LargeInt`. I took a look and saw that some searches with the count in 3.0 return a `bigInt` column, while in 2.5 it returns an integer column.

To solve the way I know, I would have to cast a cast on everything that is giving error, tested and worked, but it is a big system, it will give a lot of work.

Does anyone know of any way to resolve this in Firebird itself? Some configuration, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Unidac, and for the solution I used Map Rules (Data Type Mapping).

Answer (score 3):

There is no configuration for it; the [Firebird 3 release notes only say](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-countresult):

> The `COUNT()` aggregator now returns its result as `BIGINT` instead of `INTEGER`.

You either need to explicitly apply a cast in your queries, or in your code, or see if your data access library can explicitly request integer instead of just the dynamic type. For example in the Java world the JDBC API has an explicit `getInt` which will work for `BIGINT` as long as the value fits in a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use TYPECAST in SQL in any delphi component and will be ok. For example wite:

```
select
cast(count(*) as integer) BR
from ...
```

instead of

```
select
count(*) BR
from ...
```